# How to get all ContentTypes from a Site Collection in a SharePoint Farm

Tags: sharepoint, content-type

How to get all ContentTypes from a Site Collection in a SharePoint Farm. Remember, I want to do this using the SharePoint Object Model. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
public void ListContentTypes(string siteUrl)
{
  try
  {
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
        ListContentTypes(web);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // add some proper error handling here
  }
}

public void ListContentTypes(SPWeb web)
{
  foreach (SPContentType ct in web.ContentTypes)
  {
    // do whatever you want to do with the content type here
  }

  foreach (SPWeb subWeb in web.Webs)
  {
    try
    {
      ListContentTypes(subWeb);
    }
    finally
    {
      if (subWeb != null)
      {
        subWeb.Dispose();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will find all content types that exist in the site collection, but remember that not all content types will be available in the entire site collection. For example: if you have a content type 'Product' that exists in a subsite, the code above will find it but you won't be able to use it in the root web because it's defined in a lower level.

Answer (score 4):

This one will do it for all types in all SPWeb's in a Site. Note this will produce duplicates.

```
    public void GetContentTypes()
    {
        string siteUrl = "Add site url here";

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
        {
                foreach (SPWeb web in site.AllWebs)
                {
                    foreach (SPContentType item in web.ContentTypes)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
                    }
                    foreach (SPList list in web.Lists)
                    {
                        foreach (SPContentType item in list.ContentTypes)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine(item.Name);
                        }
                    }
                    web.Dispose();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have to look all the webs, not just the rootweb!

Comment: You need to dispose each SPWeb obtained with site.AllWebs

Comment: This should return all the SITE content types, but it won't get all the LIST content types too. I can't think why you'd want to, but it's worth recognising the difference. http://www.novolocus.com/2008/03/28/content-types-whos-your-daddy/

Comment: @Andy, thanks for the comment, I have updated the code to iterate through lists as well.

Comment: I have tested the code and i'm sorry to say that its an infinite loop!

Comment: I have run a unit test against this code and there was not an infinate loop. But the time it took to run the test went up dramatically when I added the for each for the lists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one :urWeb.AvailableContentTypes

Comment: Does it include all available installed ContentTypes selected/non-selected and used/non-used?

Comment: The problem with this property is that it will not give you the content types that are defined at a lower level. So it does not return all content types from a site collection. It gives you the content types defined in a specific web and all its parent webs.